# UIkit.pagination is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, getuikit

I am using UIkit Pagination and it didn't work. I know I have UIkit installed in my environment as I'm using the UIkit Modal, uploadDrop, uploadSelect, etc and these are running perfectly.

Here is my HTML for pagination buttons:

```
<ul id = "PaginateDsData" class="uk-pagination"></ul>
```

and this is the Javascript:

```
var pagination = UIkit.pagination($('#PaginateDsData'), {
                    items:100,
                    itemsOnPage:10,
                    displayedPages:10
                /* options */ });
```

I've been reading the documentation of this dynamic uikit pagination currently at https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/pagination-js.html but I am still unable to run it successfully.

Comment: Make sure you included jQuery and pagination component.

Comment: the only thing are needed is the uikit css and uikit.min.js which I already included in my page.

Answer (score 1):

According to UIkit's documentation it requires jQuery. https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/documentation_get-started.html#html-page-markup
Also the core UIkit doesn't come with dynamic pagination component. https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/pagination.html#javascript

Here is a working example of dynamic pagination.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.uk-pagination');
var pagination = UIkit.pagination(element, {
                  items:100,
                  itemsOnPage:10,
                  displayedPages:10
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/uikit.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="uk-pagination"></ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/pagination.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.